# expect script running out of sync?

Tags: tcl, expect, cisco

I'm currently modifying a script used to backup cisco ACE modules' contexts & crypto files.  it works absolutely beautifully with one device.  however, when i use it on another module, it seems to go completely out of sync and it messes up the script.

From what I can see, the differences are in the presence of a line that the ACE module throws up as so:   `Warning: Permanently added '[x.x.x.x]' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\r\n`  this just seems to throw the rest of the script off, even though none of my expect statements are even looking for this!

I've had nothing but nightmares with expect and the way in which it interprets information from ace modules; can anyone shed any light on this issue or provide any advice as to how to make these devices behave when I try to script for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're handling one connection at a time, you should make sure you *fully* terminate one  before opening the next. The simplest way of doing that is to put:

```
close
wait
```

At the end of the (`foreach`) loop over the things to connect to.

---

If you were doing multiple connections at once, you'd have to take care to use the `-i` option  to various commands (notably `expect`, `send` and `close`) and make everything work right *in addition* to fixing the things I mentioned earlier. It *can* be done, but it's considerably more tricky and not worth it if you don't need the parallelism.